# Jest reports that test passes even though expect assertion fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, codesandbox

In [this code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nk6rv45oz4) the following test is executed:

```
    import { of } from "rxjs";
    import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

    const source = of("World");

    test("It should fail", () => {
      source.subscribe(x => expect(x).toContain("NOTHING"));
    });
```

Jest reports it as passing, even though the expectation fails.  Thoughts?

Comment: The expectation comes *after* the test ends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rxjs observables are asynchronous. Take a look at [this page](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous.html) to help with testing asynchronous code

You want to add the done argument as below ->

```
test("It should fail", done => {
  source.subscribe(
    x => {
      expect(x).toContain("NOTHING")
      done();
    });
});
```

Comment: Funny enough the observable he's testing is _not_ asynchronous. So this seems like a bug in Jest.

Comment: The observable itself may not be asynchronous, but the subscribe call is, and Jest completes the test prior to the expect call being reached