# Jest assertion fails unless I console.log the expected value before the assertion (Code is not async)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm testing a synchronous middleware stack that I derived from expressjs. For some reason my tests are passing even though the assertions *should* fail. I know from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53197952/jest-reports-that-test-passes-even-though-expect-assertion-fails) question that the .subscribe calls are asynchronous in JEST, but I'm not using any `subscribe` calls, only `expect`. I believe that the issue has to do with the test finishing before all of the `expect()` calls complete. But given the implementation, I'm not sure how that's possible.

```
test( "Stack proceeds to next error-handling layer if next(error) is explicitly called", () => {
    const S = new Stack();

    S.use( () => {
        throw new Error( "FAIL" );
    });

    S.use( ( err, data, next ) => {
        console.log( err.message) // Prints "FAIL"
        expect( err.message ).toBe( "PASS" ); // Always passes no matter what
        next( err )
    });

    let SKIP_TEST = "PASS";
    S.use( ( data, next ) => {
        SKIP_TEST = "FAIL";
    });

    let CALL_TEST = "FAIL";
    S.use( ( err, data, next ) => {
        CALL_TEST = "PASS";
        // adding a console.log( err.message ) here causes this test to fail, which is the expected behavior. Without a console.log on this line, the test will always pass
        expect( err.message ).toBe( "PASS" );
    });


    S.dispatch(); // Causes the above functions to be called synchronously, in the order they were defined

    expect( SKIP_TEST ).toBe( "PASS" ); // Passes
    expect( CALL_TEST ).toBe( "PASS" ); // Passes
});
```

I know that the functions passed to .use are being called because I can console.log from them and the output shows up in the console. To make things even more strange, adding a console.log call right before the expect in the final S.use function causes the assertion to (correctly) fail.

Here is the middleware stack that I derived from express.js

```
"use strict"

export default class Stack {
    constructor(){
        this.stack = [];
    }

    dispatch( data, done = ()=>{} ){
        let idx = 0;
        let stack = this.stack;
        if( stack.length === 0 )
            done();

        next();

        function next( err ){
            let layer = stack[ idx++ ];
            if( !layer )
                return done( err );
            if( err )
                layer.handleError( err, data, next );
            else
                layer.handleNext( data, next );
        }
    }

    use( fn ){
        this.stack.push( new Layer( fn ) );
    }

}

class Layer {
    constructor( fn ){
        // if( !this instanceof Layer )
        //      return new Layer( fn );
        this.handle = fn;
        this.name = fn.name || "<anonymous>";
    }

    handleError( err, data, next ){
        let fn = this.handle;

        // If this layer is not an error-handler, pass error to next layer
        if( fn.length !== 3 )
            return next( err ); // Stop the chain unless next() is explicitly called by the next layer in the stack

        try{
            fn( err, data, next );
        } catch( err ){
            next( err );
        }
    }

    handleNext( data, next ){
        let fn = this.handle;

        // If this layer is not a standard handler, skip this layer
        if( fn.length > 2 )
            return next(); // Stop the chain unless next() is explicitly called by the next layer in the stack

        try{
            fn( data, next );
        } catch( err ) {
            next( err );
        }
    }
}
export{ Stack }
```

[here is a complete reproduction of the issue.](https://repl.it/@TyMeador/LightsalmonScornfulUnits#Stack.test.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I cannot explain why the issue was happening, I managed to work around it by only calling `expect()` after the `dispatch()` call. I used a bunch of boolean flags that are set when the corresponding middleware stack is called.

**The key is not to call `expect(...)` inside of a function that is passed as a parameter**

This is what the correct test ended up being

```
test( "MiddlewareStack proceeds to next error-handling layer if 
next(error) is explicitly called", function() {
    const S = new MiddlewareStack();

    // Test flags
    let STD_HANDLER_WAS_CALLED = false;
    let FIRST_ERR_HANDLER_RECEIVED_ERROR = false;
    let FIRST_ERR_HANDLER_RECEIVED_CORRECT_ERROR = false;
    let SECOND_ERR_HANDLER_RECEIVED_ERROR = false;
    let SECOND_ERR_HANDLER_RECEIVED_CORRECT_ERROR = false;
    let SECOND_ERR_HANDLER_WAS_CALLED = false;

    S.use( () => {
        throw new Error( "PASS" );
    });

    S.use( ( err, data, next ) => {
        if( err ){
            FIRST_ERR_HANDLER_RECEIVED_ERROR = true;
            if( err.message === "PASS" )
                FIRST_ERR_HANDLER_RECEIVED_CORRECT_ERROR = true;
        }
        next( err )
    });

    S.use( ( data, next ) => {
        STD_HANDLER_WAS_CALLED = true;
    });

    S.use( ( err, data, next ) => {
        SECOND_ERR_HANDLER_WAS_CALLED = true;
        if( err ){
            SECOND_ERR_HANDLER_RECEIVED_ERROR = true;
            if( err.message === "PASS" )
                SECOND_ERR_HANDLER_RECEIVED_CORRECT_ERROR = true;
        }
    });

    S.dispatch();
    expect( FIRST_ERR_HANDLER_RECEIVED_ERROR ).toBe( true );
    expect( FIRST_ERR_HANDLER_RECEIVED_CORRECT_ERROR ).toBe( true );
    expect( STD_HANDLER_WAS_CALLED ).toBe( false );
    expect( SECOND_ERR_HANDLER_WAS_CALLED ).toBe( true );
    expect( SECOND_ERR_HANDLER_RECEIVED_ERROR ).toBe( true );
    expect( SECOND_ERR_HANDLER_RECEIVED_CORRECT_ERROR ).toBe( true );
});
```